# Failed to load r_cart

Tags: microcontroller, simulation, pr2

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Dear All.
while I following the step from the website:
http://www.ros.org/wiki/pr2_simulator/Tutorials/Teleop%20PR2%20arm%20in%20simulation

1. roscore
2. roslaunch pr2_gazebo pr2_empty_world.launch
3. roslaunch jtteleop.launch
   Then from the terminal I find the following information
   administrator@ubuntu:~$ roslaunch jtteleop.launch
   ... logging to /home/administrator/.ros/log/ea179d4e-5728-11e1-af87-18f46a4fafa8/roslaunch-ubuntu-19389.log
   Checking log directory for disk usage. This may take awhile.
   Press Ctrl-C to interrupt
   Done checking log file disk usage. Usage is <1GB.

started roslaunch server http://ubuntu:58130/

## SUMMARY

PARAMETERS

- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_forearm_roll_joint
- /r_cart/pose_command_filter
- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_shoulder_pan_joint
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_shoulder_lift_joint
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_elbow_flex_joint
- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_wrist_flex_joint
- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_upper_arm_roll_joint
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_shoulder_pan_joint
- /rosdistro
- /r_cart/vel_saturation_trans
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_wrist_roll_joint
- /r_cart/cart_gains/trans/d
- /rosversion
- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_shoulder_lift_joint
- /r_cart/cart_gains/trans/p
- /r_cart/type
- /r_cart/tip_name
- /r_cart/vel_saturation_rot
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_forearm_roll_joint
- /r_cart/cart_gains/rot/p
- /r_cart/root_name
- /r_cart/jacobian_inverse_damping
- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_elbow_flex_joint
- /r_cart/k_posture
- /r_cart/cart_gains/rot/d
- /r_cart/joint_max_effort/r_wrist_roll_joint
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_upper_arm_roll_joint
- /r_cart/joint_feedforward/r_wrist_flex_joint

NODES
/
stop_r_arm (pr2_controller_manager/pr2_controller_manager)
spawn_cart (pr2_controller_manager/spawner)

ROS_MASTER_URI=http://localhost:11311

core service [/rosout] found
process[stop_r_arm-1]: started with pid [19407]
process[spawn_cart-2]: started with pid [19408]
[stop_r_arm-1] process has finished cleanly.
log file: /home/administrator/.ros/log/ea179d4e-5728-11e1-af87-18f46a4fafa8/stop_r_arm-1*.log
[ERROR] [WallTime: 1329237265.196718] [254.818000] Failed to load r_cart

I am in ubuntu 11.10 , electric ros package.
I also rosmake pr2_controller_manager
and download the source code from svn teleop_controllers.
Thanks for any help.
Zhenli

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/27605/failed-to-load-r_cart/) by [zhenli](https://answers.ros.org/users/1716/zhenli/) on ROS Answers with karma: 287 on 2012-02-14

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

in ROS Electric the controller moved to the robot_mechanism_controllers package.

In the launch file you had to create during the tutorial, change the controller type from "JTTeleopController" to "robot_mechanism_controllers/JTCartesianController". Then it should work.

Best,
Juergen

---

Originally posted by [JuergenHess](https://answers.ros.org/users/370/juergenhess/) with karma: 86 on 2012-02-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3